# log4cxx::AsyncAppender, All logs are not logged before exiting

Tags: log4j, log4cxx

I am using default AsyncAppender and ODBCAppender class as a reference to AsyncAppender.

properly specified the configurations and blocking option as false.
All logs dont get logged.
for log count greater than (size of AsyncAppenderBuffer plus size of DBAppender) only log count equal to the sum of these sizes gets logged.

Answer (score 1):

Appenders are flushed by a call to [`log4cxx::LogManager::shutdown()`](https://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/latest_stable/classlog4cxx_1_1LogManager.html#ad8845f4e8c6c840c7825bde2c9ce7e7c).